# How to access a website running on my localhost(host/server) to Serial Monitor using ESP8266(Client)?

Tags: esp8266, wifi

The following source code is from the official ESP8266 website(Explanation provided): https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/client-examples.html
This .ino code returns the html code of the server name mentioned in "const char* server" declaration, on to the Serial Monitor.

And Yes, this code perfectly returned the html codes of wwww.google.com, www.arduino.cc etc. But when I try it with my 'led blinking.html' I am unable to find any luck. I guess it is because the website should be hosted on a live server.

**Other Details:**
1. uC Board: Wemos D1 mini (An ESP8266 Variant)
2. I am using Xampp to run Apache server and MySQL
3. Wemos board is set up as a WiFiClient

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "xxxxx";
const char* password = "xxxxxxxx";
```

**I have put the html,php code of the website in the directory :** C:/xampp/htdocs/LED BLINKING/led blinking.html

**IP Address of my Windows PC:** 192.168.100.9

```
const char* server = "192.168.100.9/LED BLINKING/led blinking.html";
```

I tried with just "192.168.100.9"; too.
I also unblocked the windows firewall for my ApacheHTTP Server. Now I can view the webpage on my mobile with the URL: 192.168.100.9/LED BLINKING/led blinking.html.

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();

  Serial.printf("Connecting to %s ", ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println(" connected");
}


void loop()
{
  WiFiClient client;

  Serial.printf("\n[Connecting ...");
  if (client.connect(server, 80))
  {
    Serial.println("connected]");

    Serial.println("[Sending a request]");
    client.print(String("GET /") + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                 "server: " + server + "\r\n" +
                 "Connection: close\r\n" +
                 "\r\n"
                );

   Serial.println("[Response:]");
    while (client.connected())
    {
      if (client.available())
      {
        String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
        Serial.println(line);
      }
    }
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("\n[Disconnected]");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("connection failed!]");
    client.stop();
  }
  delay(5000);
}
```

The output on Serial Monitor is:
Connecting to ssid connected
[Connecting connection failed!]

Answer (score 2):

Variable `server` is a hostname or IP address for TCP connection.
The `/LED BLINKING/led blinking.html` goes after HTTP GET. Now there is `/` and it worked for main page of servers.

You need

```
client.print(String("GET /LED%20BLINKING/led%20blinking.htm") + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
             "server: " + server + "\r\n" +
             "Connection: close\r\n" +
             "\r\n"
            );
```

and you must escape the space